# Training and evaluating bigram/trigram distributions with NgramModel in nltk, using Witten Bell Smoothing

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

I would like to train an NgramModel on one set of sentences, using Witten-Bell smoothing to estimate the unseen ngrams, and then use it to get the log-likelihood of a test set having been generated by that distribution. I want to do almost the same thing as in the documentation example found here: http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/model/ngram.html, but with Witten-Bell smoothing instead. Here's some toy code trying to do about what I want to do:

```
from nltk.probability import WittenBellProbDist
from nltk import NgramModel

est = lambda fdist, bins: WittenBellProbDist(fdist)
fake_train = [str(t) for t in range(3000)]
fake_test = [str(t) for t in range(2900, 3010)]

lm = NgramModel(2, fake_train, estimator = est)

print lm.entropy(fake_test)
```

Unfortunately, when I try running that, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ngram.py", line 8, in <module>
    lm = NgramModel(2, fake_train, estimator = est)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/model/ngram.py", line 63, in __init__
    self._model = ConditionalProbDist(cfd, estimator, len(cfd))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 2016, in __init__
    **factory_kw_args)
  File "ngram.py", line 4, in <lambda>
    est = lambda fdist, bins: WittenBellProbDist(fdist)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 1210, in __init__
    self._P0 = self._T / float(self._Z * (self._N + self._T))
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

What's causing this error? As far as I can tell I'm using everything correctly according to the documentation, and this works fine when I use Lidstone instead of Witten-Bell.

As a second question, I have data in the form of a collection of disjoint sentences. How can I use the sentences like a list of lists of strings, or do something equivalent that would produce the same distribution? (i.e. of course I could just use a list that has all the sentences with a dummy token separating subsequent sentences, but that wouldn't produce the same distribution.) The documentation in one place says that a list of list of strings is allowed, but then I found a bug report where the documentation was supposedly edited to reflect that that wasn't allowed (and when I just try a list of lists of strings I get an error).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everyone. I ended up going with SRILM instead since that code is actually complete and seemingly correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its apparently been a known issue for [almost 3 years](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=538). The reason for `ZeroDivisionError` is because of the following lines in `__init__`,

```
if bins == None: 
    bins = freqdist.B() 
self._freqdist = freqdist 
self._T = self._freqdist.B() 
self._Z = bins - self._freqdist.B()
```

Whenever the `bins` argument is not specified, it defaults to `None` so `self._Z` is really just `freqdist.B() - freqdist.B()` and

```
self._P0 = self._T / float(self._Z * (self._N + self._T))
```

reduces down to,

```
self._P0 = freqdist.B() / 0.0
```

Additionally, if you specify `bins` as any value greater than `freqdist.B()`, in executing this line of your code,

```
print lm.entropy(fake_test)
```

you will receive `NotImplementedError` because within the `WittenBellProbDist` class,

```
def discount(self): 
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

The `discount` method is apparently also used in `prob` and `logprob` of the `NgramModel` class so you won't be able to call them either.

One way to fix these problems, without changing `NLTK`, would be to inherit from `WittenBellProbDist` and override the relevant methods.

Answer (score 1):

## Update Dec 2018

NLTK 3.4 contains the reworked ngram modeling module importable as `nltk.lm`

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from NLTK's NgramModel for the time being. There is currently a smoothing bug that causes the model to greatly overestimate likelihoods when n>1. This applies for all estimators including WittenBellProbDist and even LidstoneProbDist. I think this error has been around for a few years, suggesting that this part of NLTK is not well tested.

See:
https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/367

Comment: That makes sense -- I had noticed that the conditional probabilities given a token did not add up to 1 when summed over all possible tokens. I was a little worried for a while before realizing that since suddenly the baseline was killing my much more sophisticated method, heh.